# Does rupa jhana mean material or fine material?

Tags: jhana

Does rupa regarding jhana mean material or fine (subtle) material according to Buddhism? According to [source](https://buddhist-spirituality.org/eightfold-path/right-concentration) it says:

> This is the first of the Absorptions belonging to the Fine-Material
> Sphere (rupavacarajjhana). It is attained when, through the strength
> of concentration, the fivefold sense activity is temporarily
> suspended, and the five Hindrances are likewise eliminated. (Dîgha
> Nikaya, 22)

Comment: https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sagga/loka.html#rupa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no definitive answer to this question.

The jhana evangelists of the Ajahn Brahm sect say 'rupa' or 'form' refers to the mental image (nimitta) in jhana. But I personally do not agree with this.

The Suttas (e.g. [SN 36.22](https://suttacentral.net/sn36.22/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=plain&reference=none&notes=none&highlight=true&script=latin)) refers to bodily feelings (piti & sukha) & mental feelings (such as domanassa & somanassa). The jhana are based in piti, sukha & equanimity feelings. In other words, the piti & sukha of jhana is generated by the nervous system of physical body or rupa. Even though the rupa cannot be experienced in jhana, the piti & sukha experienced in jhana have their source in the rupa. Similarly, the equanimity of the 4th jhana is the absence of piti & sukha manifesting in the physical body. The suttas also say breathing is the 'thorn' of the 4th jhana, which probably means if/when the 4th jhana starts to weaken, the breathing is the 1st thing experienced. This is probably why jhana is called rupa jhana.

The breathing is physical. When the breathing is calmed by mental absorption into the breathing, this causes piti & sukha to manifest. Thus piti & sukha jhana that (previously) used absorption into breathing as its cause for fruition is probably called 'rupa jhana'.

Comment: Would u agree breath, piti, sukha, nimitta are all fine material?

Comment: There is no word in Pali that means "fine" material. Rupa means "material"

Answer (score 1):

Rupa means any form , organic or inorganic, fine or coarse, biological or technological.

Answer (score -1):

It's same meaning but it's difference in detail.

For example, there are only three senses for Rupa-Bhrhama while human have six senses because of the difference head-Taṇha to rebirth.

See [AbhidhammatthaSangaha Chapter 1-6](https://thaipitaka.gitlab.io/sangaha/index.html) for more detail.